# Download from an SFTP server then upload to anther SFTP server

Tags: c#, download, upload, sftp, ssh.net

How would I go about downloading from an **SFTP(A)** server using SSN.Net and at the same time upload to anther **SFTP(B)** server. The files I’m transferring are very large (eg  **10GB**).
Is it possible to **download then simultaneously upload** to SFTP(B), or do I first need to save it to a FileStream (while downloading from the SFTP(A) server), then use the FileStream to uploaded it to another SFTP(B) Server?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SSH.NET/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to do it like this using SSH.Net client

```
using (var sftpFileStream = sftpClient1.Create($"/Destination/{fileName}"))
{
   sftpClient2.DownloadFile($"/Source/{fileName}", sftpFileStream);
}
```